# ActiveAdmin filter boolean with Nil Value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-6, ransack

I use my Rails app to see if guests will participate to an event.

I have a Guest model that has a `participate` boolean.
This boolean is initialised as `Nil` for all new Guests. By initialising it in this way I can actually know if a Guest will join or not.

I am using ActiveAdmin and I am trying to filter the participate boolean by its three potential values: `nil`, `true`, `false`.

My `app/admin/guests.rb` looks like this

```
ActiveAdmin.register Guest do
  permit_params :user_id, :participate, :name

  index do
    selectable_column
    column :id
    column :user, sortable: :user_id
    column :participate do |value|
      if value.participate
        "Yes"
      elsif value.participate.nil?
        "Null"
      else
        "No"
      end
    end
    actions
  end

  filter :participate, as: :check_boxes, collection:[["Yes", true], ["No", false], ["Null", nil]]
end
```

With the custom column I was able to show the `Nil` values in the ActiveAdmin table, but I cannot make the participate filter work and the filter example above is what I need to have from a UX perspective.
In the participate filter, the `Yes` and `No` options work as expected but for some reason if I select `Null` (i.e. `nil`) the filter does not work and the query responds:

```markdown
 Current filters: None
```

I believe I might need to somehow customise the filter with Ransack but having gone through the docs I cannot understand how to make it work since I am using it through ActiveAdmin.

I kind of made it work with the following:

```
filter :participate_null, as: :boolean, label: "Answer Missing?"
filter :participate_true, as: :boolean, label: "Participate True"
filter :participate_false, as: :boolean, label: "Participate False"
```

but this makes the user interface super complicated and not intuitive at all thus making this solution pretty much not usable.

Answer (score 0):

Actually managed to solve this by adding a custom ransacker filter in the Guest model:

```
ransacker :participate_status_filter, formatter: proc { |value|
  results = Guest.where(participate: true).map(&:id) if value == "true"
  results = Guest.where(participate: false).map(&:id) if value == "false"
  results = Guest.where(participate: nil).map(&:id) if value == "nil"
  results
} do |parent|
  parent.table[:id]
end
```

Whereas the `app/admin/guests.rb` looks like:

```
filter :participate_status_filter, as: :check_boxes,  label: "Participate", collection:[["Yes", true], ["No", false], ["Null", :nil]]
```

Many thanks to this [article](https://medium.com/@lowellmower/custom-filters-in-activeadmin-filtering-a-nil-value-with-ransacker-and-activeadmin-fe8c0fedee35#.5qdp96na9) for actually enabling me to understand how to properly use Ransacker with ActiveAdmin